# Proof for integer division algorithm that rounds up

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, algorithms, computer-science, integers

Recently I came across an [algorithm for integer division on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7446742) that rounds up.

If we have two numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and we want to divide $b$ into $a$ such that the result is always rounded up, we can use:

$$f(a, b) = \frac{(a + b - 1)}{b}$$

Now, if we take an easy example:

$$f(5, 3) = \frac{(5 + 3 - 1)}{3} = 2.\overline{3}$$

Which, since we assume integer division, will be cut off from $2.\overline{3}$ to $2$

Is there a formal proof for this algorithm that demonstrates that the algorithm will always return a result big enough so that the mantissa of the result can be cut off because of integer division?

Comment: $\frac{a+b-1}{b}=\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b}$.  The value of $\frac{b-1}{b}$ is always less than 1.

Comment: @NicNic8 nice and elegant, very good! If you write an answer I gladly accept it.

Comment: Thanks; I've written an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{a+b-1}{b}=\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b}$.  The value of $\frac{b-1}{b}$ is always less than 1.  Now let's take the floor of both sides.

If $b$ divides $a$ then
$\lfloor\frac{a+b-1}{b}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b}\rfloor = \frac{a}{b}.$

Now let's analyze the case where $b$ doesn't divide $a$.  In this case, as before, $\lfloor\frac{a+b-1}{b}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b}\rfloor$.
Let's say that $\frac{a}{b} = w\frac{r}{b}$ where $w$ is an integer and $r$ is the remainder.  Then we know that $0 < r < b-1$.  Therefore, $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b-1}{b}=w\frac{r}{b}+\frac{b-1}{b} = (w+1)\frac{k}{b}$ where $k\geq 0$.  If we then take the floor of both sides, we get $\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor=w+1$.  That is to say, $\lfloor\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b}\rfloor =\lceil\frac{a}{b}\rceil$.

Comment: The only part I'm still struggling with, when $b$ doesn't divide $a$ - then why is it clear that the remainder of the division $a \div b$ plus $(b-1) \div b$ is enough to "fill it up" to the next integer.

Comment: @Max Please see my edited answer; I hope that clears it up.